# Regex to replace |foo| with abs(foo)

Tags: regex, replace, sed, grep, full-text-search

I've got a large LaTeX document, and I'm looking to change the formatting of places where I've used absolute-value notation. Ideally I'd do this automatically, but I'm unsure of how to construct the regex to do so.

I've looked at other questions on this site, and many deal with how to replace (foo) with abs(foo), but the problem is that '(' and ')' are different characters, while the beginning and end absolute value brackets are identical.

I'm thinking that I somehow have to count the '|' instances to see if there is an even or odd number occurring.

I'm working under the assumption that | foo | bar | baz | is always converted to abs(foo) bar abs(baz) i.e.there is no nesting.

Is there a way to do this? I've used a bit of grep, but not much sed or perl, so I'm not clear on how to do the search and replace.

Comment: Why do you think this is any harder than parentheses? Try the same thing, but replace the parens with pipes, and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Are there any assumptions about whether spaces exist on either side of the `|`? For example, if it's an absolute value, then `|foo|` would have a space before the first `|` and a space after the second `|`. Whereas, with `|foo|bar|baz|` or even `|foo|bar|` (which has a different semantic meaning than absolute value) your regex can check for the non-space after the second `|` before calling it an `abs`. I know I'm making a few assumptions here...

Comment: Sadly, I don't think the spacing is consistent enough to do that.

Answer (score 4):

try this sed line:

```
sed -r 's/([^|]*)\|([^|]+)\|/\1abs(\2)/g' file.tex
```

**note**

- I used `-r` to save some escaping.
- this substitution is risky, you have to test. because sed doesn't know in your text, which case is an absolute-value notation, which case is an logical or notation, or bit-wise "or" operation. if your text has those.

with your example:

```
kent$  echo " | foo | bar | baz |"|sed -r 's/([^|]*)\|([^|]+)\|/\1abs(\2)/g'                                                                                                
 abs( foo ) bar abs( baz )
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need to capture the stuff before: `'s/\|([^|]+)\|/abs(\1)/g'`

Comment: Thx. yes yours is better, the `\1` in my regex is not necessary.